# Annotation reflection (using getAnnotation) does not work

Tags: java, jpa, reflection, annotations, persistence

I have to following code to check whether the entity in my `model` has a `nullable=false` or similar annotation on a field.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import .....

private boolean isRequired(Item item, Object propertyId) {
        Class<?> property = getPropertyClass(item, propertyId);

        final JoinColumn joinAnnotation = property.getAnnotation(JoinColumn.class);
        if (null != joinAnnotation) {
            return !joinAnnotation.nullable();
        }

        final Column columnAnnotation = property.getAnnotation(Column.class);
        if (null != columnAnnotation) {
            return !columnAnnotation.nullable();
        }

        ....
        return false;
    }
```

Here's a snippet from my model.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import .....

@Entity
@Table(name="m_contact_details")
public class MContactDetail extends AbstractMasterEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(length=60, nullable=false)
    private String address1;
```

For those people unfamiliar with the `@Column` annotation, here's the header:

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Column {
```

I'd expect the `isRequired` to return `true` every now and again, but instead it never does. 
I've already done a `mvn clean` and `mvn install` on my project, but that does not help.

Q1: What am I doing wrong?

Q2: is there a cleaner way to code `isRequired` (perhaps making better use of generics)?

Comment: Is you `@Column` annotation persistent? Is it maybe always `null`? Can you share part of the `@Column` interface?

Comment: It's part of the `javax.persistence` api.

Comment: Notice that `@Column` is an annotation on a field, not on a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `property` represents a class (it's a `Class<?>`)
2. `@Column` and `@JoinColumn` can only annotate fields/methods.

Consequently you will never find these annotations on `property`.

A slightly modified version of your code that prints out whether the email property of the Employee entity is required:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
      System.out.println(isRequired(Employee.class, "email"));
}

private static boolean isRequired(Class<?> entity, String propertyName) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    Field property = entity.getDeclaredField(propertyName);

    final JoinColumn joinAnnotation = property.getAnnotation(JoinColumn.class);
    if (null != joinAnnotation) {
        return !joinAnnotation.nullable();
    }

    final Column columnAnnotation = property.getAnnotation(Column.class);
    if (null != columnAnnotation) {
        return !columnAnnotation.nullable();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note that this is a half-baked solution, because JPA annotations can either be on a field or on a method. Also be aware of the difference between the reflection methods like `getFiled()`/`getDeclaredField()`. The former returns inherited fields too, while the latter returns only fields of the specific class ignoring what's inherited from its parents.

Comment: OK, so how do I get to the annotation for the field?

Comment: You need to get the `Field` from the `Class` object and use the same `getAnnotation()` method.

Comment: Thanks a million this was exactly what I needed, see the final working code below.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private boolean isRequired(BeanItem item, Object propertyId) throws SecurityException {

        String fieldname = propertyId.toString();

        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Field field = item.getBean().getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldname);
            final JoinColumn joinAnnotation = field.getAnnotation(JoinColumn.class);
            if (null != joinAnnotation) {
                return !joinAnnotation.nullable();
            }

            final Column columnAnnotation = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
            if (null != columnAnnotation) {
                return !columnAnnotation.nullable();
            }



        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            //not a problem no need to log this event.
            return false;
        } 
    }
```