# How to get Column Annotation using Kotlin Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to create a inline function that can return entity column name, but get error

I created that from the solution i found on [Annotation reflection (using getAnnotation) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965092/annotation-reflection-using-getannotation-does-not-work)

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", schema = "dbo")
data class Employee(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 20)
    var id: String,

    @Column(name = "employee_name", nullable = true, length = 30)
    var employeeName: String? = "",
)
```

Here is my function :

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> getColumnName(filt:String):String {

        var property = T::class.memberProperties.filter { prop -> prop.name == filt}.firstOrNull()
        var field = property!!.javaField!!
        var column = field.getAnnotation(Column::class) //error in here
        return column!!.name()
}
```

When i try this,

```
var column = field.getAnnotation(Column.class)
```

error :

```
Name expected
```

When i try this,

```
var column = field.getAnnotation(Column::class)
```

error :

```
Type inference failed: fun <T : Annotation!> getAnnotation(p0: Class<T!>!): T!
cannot be applied to
(KClass<Column>)

Type mismatch: inferred type is KClass<Column> but
Class<(???..???)>! was expected
```

am i missing something??

I would be glad for any help.

Comment: `X::class.java`. Although note that your annotation is not on the Java field, its on the Kotlin property. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html

Comment: It's work... thank you so much...